# Inline form with one select and a submit button using element UI in vue?

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

I'm using the Element library in vue (https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US) and wish to make a simple form with one select box and a submit button. I don't see a way on the site to do that.

I want something like this, but with a select box instead of the text input

```
        <el-input
          ref="searchBox"
          v-model="searchForm.searchBox"
          placeholder="Search for Units and or Clients"
          type="text"
          auto-complete="on"
          @keyup.enter.native="submitForm('searchForm')"
        >
          <el-button
            slot="append"
            icon="el-icon-search"
            :loading="loading"
            @click="submitForm('searchForm')"
          />
        </el-input>
      </el-form-item>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use the inline form attribute and not the el-input option.

```
<el-form
  ref="stateForm"
  :inline="true"
  :model="commentForm"
  :rules="rules"
>
  <el-select v-model="selectModel" placeholder="please select">
    <el-option
       v-for="(v, v_index) in optionsConstant"
       :key="v_index"
       :label="v"
       :value="v_index"
     />
  </el-select>
  <el-button type="primary" @click="submitForm('stateForm')">Submit</el-button>
</el-form>
```